# Which phrase is grammatically correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Only one of the following is correct, but I am not sure which. My answer key says that Sentence 1 is correct, but I don't understand why. Here they are:

> **Sentence 1:** Therefore, a Platonic idealist believes that these abstract forms are ***as effective as, if not more effective than***,
>   sensory experience at revealing the nature of reality.
>
> **Sentence 2:** Therefore, a Platonic idealist believes that these abstract forms are ***as effective, if not more effective, than***
>   sensory experience at revealing the nature of reality.

I still think sentence 2 sounds more syntactically accurate.

Comment: Take out the aside *if not more effective than*. You'll see that English idiom requires *as X ... as Y* for the comparison.

Comment: It sounds more familiar because the majority of people would probably say it that way; that doesn't mean it's syntactically correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're injecting a clause into the middle of an already complete sentence. This means, if you remove the clause, does the sentence still make sense?

- ... forms are as effective as sensory experience ...

  - Yep!
- ... forms are as effective than sensory experience ...

  - Nope!

Comment: Is this method of isolating the "injected" clause to inspect the grammatic accuracy of an additional clause applicable to all cases where a clause is added to a sentence?

Comment: I can't think of a situation where it isn't.